# simple android app that allows user just to choose IP and port

Tags: android, web-applications, cordova

I developed a web application for mobile devices, every customer installs the webapplication on his webserver. So I have this scenario:

> Customer 1: application at 210.132.1.23:87
>
> Customer 2: application at 210.2.13.13:9944

...

> Customer N: application at 132.1.23.14:112

With *Phone Gap* Build I was able to make a simple app (= source code) that directly opens the webapp at a fixed address, but I would like to have the option to choose the `IP:port`, I cannot make *N* apps one per customer.

**Is there a very simple andorid app that does this? Or do you know if it is possible to do this directly with *Phone Gap*?**

Thanks.

*Note: Of course it is possbile to develop this feature, anyway since I am totally new to this world, and as far as I can see in the next future all I need is this if Can find it "ready" it would be very good.*

Comment: Do you want customers to select from the list of all available hosts or just customize your application for every customer in a simple manner?

Comment: i want the user be able to type in the host (like 210.132.1.23:87). The simplest feature is type one only host, and this would be also the best feature. The app can have just a splash screen and then a list with the host/hosts defined (only one in case we allow single host). And then a as the user clicks on a listitem open the browser at the desired address. THne in android menu simply have delete host, add host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented the similar solution in PhoneGap + jQM. In our case though we have kept a public service which returns list of server to avoid manual typing.

I have put a quick (and dirty) solution in following fiddle. This might not be what you are looking for but may give you some idea. It is more or less what @ChrLipp has already mentioned.

http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/qcRuD/

Let me know if you would like to add anything.

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide an option dialog within your webapp which is also available offline. On first startup you force the user to enter this data. On following startups you redirect the user to a dynamic build URL. You store the ip address with HTML5 storage mechanism.

Alternatively - not possible with Phonegap build since this service only accept the webapp part and therefore doesn't allow native extensions - you mix native options with the webapp. The settings are implemented native, when you enter the phonegap activity, you use the URL from the options.

But it is very hard to provide you with specific answers since you don't state which (gui) framework(s) you are using.

Comment: I use Delphi with Raudus, but some will apply if using other Delphi RAD web app developement frameworks like UniGUI or Intraweb/VCLforTheWeb.